# Why are nodeids inconsistent in the cluster?

Tags: cnosdb

cnosdb version: enterprise 2.3.4

Result of sql `SHOW DATANODES;`.

```
+---------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| NODE_ID             | HOST                                  | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS      | DISK_FREE | LOCATION | LAST_UPDATED_TIME   |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1703747750800040865 | cnosdbpro-tskv-2.cnosdbpro-tskv.admin | HOT       | NODISKSPACE | 0 B       |          | 2024-01-29 06:20:09 |
| 1703747750800040866 | cnosdbpro-tskv-1.cnosdbpro-tskv.admin | HOT       | HEALTHY     | 2.02 GB   |          | 2024-01-29 06:20:06 |
| 1703747750800040867 | cnosdbpro-tskv-0.cnosdbpro-tskv.admin | HOT       | HEALTHY     | 2.02 GB   |          | 2024-01-29 06:20:07 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Result of sql `SELECT DISTINCT NODE_ID FROM HTTP_DATA_IN;`

```
+---------+
| node_id |
+---------+
| 1545    |
| 1481    |
| 1476    |
+---------+
```

There should be three nodes in my cluster, corresponding to three nodeids. Why do I get two different sets of nodeids? Is there a problem with the configuration?